# ResourceBundle - MissingResourceException - restarting the server solves the problem

Tags: jsp, stripes, resourcebundle

A web application throws MissingResourceException when JSP access a property in the ResourceBundle.

When the application starts, it is able to access the resource bundles and read the values from them. After sometime, the application throws MissingResourceException when the same set of pages tries to access the resource bundles. The problem goes away when the server is restarted or resource bundles are reloaded by clearing the cache. No changes are made to the resource bundles while the application is up. The presentation tier framework used is Stripes.

Comment: I know this is a substantially long time ago, but on the off chance that someone sees this post, did you get this resolved somehow?  I'm seeing the exact same issue (although using DatabaseResourceBundle).

Answer (score 0):

Resource files are loaded when the application server starts. If you add entries in them or modify them, you will need to restart the server to make these changes available in your JSP files.

Comment: edited the question to make it clear. the resource files are not modified while the application is up and running. My problem is not the case where a jsp is not able to read an updated resource bundle. Please see the updated question above and provide your comments

Comment: Could it be that you are running out of memory? Please post full stack trace and provide more details: app server and source code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it concerning StripesResources.properties?  Is there a StripesResources.properties present?

Stripes doesn't like when this properties file isn't present in the classpath, but it won't complain until it encounters a situation when it needs it (likely for a validation error).  Redeploying might be a sufficient event, because Stripes changes the current encryption key for requests, or you lose the sourcePage attribute, or something.